# How to build project with unsupported class (new feature) in xcode and swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

I'm new in Apple platform and I started with xcode 7 and swift.
I want to create app for last version of iOS (9.0) but with support of 2 older versions like 8 and 7.

**Base SDK**: Latest (iOS 9.0)

**Deployment**: 7

I used UIAlertController and it's not available in iOS 7, So I can't build my project and I get error:

> ***'UIAlertController' is only availble on iOS 8.0 or newer***

My problem isn't just this class, I looking for a solution to figure out how to handle multi version-device app.
Also I read some good article like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices) but I need more info and technique about xcode 7 and swift not objective-c or old versions of xcode.

I'm confused and don't know must to create some target for each version of iOS or some project or 1 project!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if #available` clause to check iOS version at runtime. In your case it will look like following:

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        //use UIAlertController
    }
    else {
        //use UIAlertView
    }
```

Comment: very useful and thank you, My error fixed but my question still exist: How does handle an expert developer multi version app?

Comment: "How does handle an expert developer multi version app?" -  this is not a good question for Stack Overflow. SO is for more specific problems.

Comment: How do you handle this problem?